# Catch errors from A2P Starter Brands that exceed the 3,000 message per-day limit?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am building a Twilio ISV application that allows customers to register under the "Starter" A2P Brand to allow our customers to send up to 3,000 messages a day to US carriers.

I was curious if Twilio returns a specific error code to my `StatusCallback` webhook when attempting to send a quantity over 3,000 in a day or is this something that must be handled by my application before sending a request to Twilio using a MessagingService?

I'm unable to find a specific error code for this in the documentation so I'm hoping a Twilio evangelist here on StackOverflow can provide some clarity, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There are a few A2P10DLC error codes that you might encounter, including:

- [30022](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/30022): US A2P 10DLC - Rate Limits Exceeded - you've reached the limits for a phone number or campaign
- [30023](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/30023): US A2P 10DLC - Daily Message Cap Reached - you've reached your daily limit
- [30027](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/30027): US A2P 10DLC - T-Mobile Daily Message Limit Reached - you've reached the limit with T-Mobile specifically

There are also a couple of relevant warnings that may crop up:

- [30025](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/30025): US A2P 10DLC - 50% T-Mobile Daily Message Limit Consumed
- [30026](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/30026): US A2P 10DLC - 70% T-Mobile Daily Message Limit Consumed

I think the relevant error you are asking about, regarding trying to send more than 3,000 messages a day, is [30023](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/30023).

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you!